# SQLAlchemy attribute error when filtering by list attributes

Tags: sqlalchemy

After searching and trying different things I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. What I intended to happen was fill orderServicesFull with a Services object filled with database data filtered by the serviceID of orderServices.

The issue I'm running into is I cannot seem to find the correct syntax for pulling each instance of serviceID from orderServices (second line of code).

```
orderServices = DBSession.query(ServicesByOrder).filter(ServicesByOrder.orderID == request.GET['orderID']).all()

orderServicesFull = DBSession.query(Services).filter(Services.serviceID == orderServices.serviceID).all()
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'serviceID'
```

What I've tried:

In my attempt to solve this I first did a few prints to understand what was being passed. I also looked at some documentation to try understanding what was appropriate. I even tried this... lol

```
print("<---DEBUG--->")
    serviceIDs = []
    for i in range(0, len(orderServices)):
        serviceIDs.append(orderServices[i].serviceID)
        print(serviceIDs[i])
```

The idea behind this was that it was a simple list and I could work with it easier. I attempted to use that instead of the orderServices list. As you can guess that did not work either.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time

**!SOLVED!**

Well after much messing around and some more research I came up with a solution. It may not be as efficient as someone else could have came up with but it works.

My problem was coming from the fact that I wasn't aware that the list was filled with objects.

```
orderServiceList = DBSession.execute(\
"SELECT s.serviceID, s.serviceName, s.serviceCost "+\
"FROM tblServicesByOrder AS so "+\
"INNER JOIN tblServices AS s "+\
"ON so.serviceID = s.serviceID "+\
"WHERE so.orderID = 1").fetchall()

orderServicesFull = [row for row in orderServiceList]
```

Doing this allowed me to create a dictionary list with the data I needed and then from there fill my orderServicesFull.

I hope this helps someone else having this same issue or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your first code snippet, the `orderServices` variable is in fact a list. Therefore, you cannot use  `orderServices.ID` in the second query (the error you get explains that).
You should be able to get all the services using `ORM` query with a `join`:

```
orderServicesFull = (DBSession.query(Services)
    .join(ServicesByOrder, Services.serviceID == ServicesByOrder.serviceID)
    .filter(ServicesByOrder.orderID == request.GET['orderID'])
    ).all()
```

*If you have a (just one) relationship defined between `Services` and `ServicesByOrder`, then the join does not require the `clause` parameter and becomes `.join(ServicesByOrder)`*

Comment: Interesting.. does this sequence of join and filter gets translated into SQL?
If not, I would not do this on anything but tiny tables. It's better to do joins and filtering at the database level.